# DataTable responsive display certain columns

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) along with [responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive) and facing issues while trying to display only certain columns.

Table layout is like this:
[image]

I need to display to only `'Column 1', 'Column3', 'Column 7', 'Column 8', 'Column 10'` and hide others( these should be displayed by expand control at the end of each row ).

**JS:**

```
  $( 'table' ).DataTable( {
      order: [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets: -1
        } ]
    } );
```

This is the [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ntsp4hsr/). Any suggestions!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To show specific columns in responsive datatable, you just need to add **[`Class Controls`](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/classes.html)** in `th` of table, as follow:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all">Column 1</th>
      <th class="none">Column 2</th>
      <th class="all">Column 3</th>
      <th class="none">Column 4</th>
      <th class="none">Column 5</th>
      <th class="none">Column 6</th>
      <th class="all">Column 7</th>
      <th class="all">Column 8</th>
      <th class="none">Column 9</th>
      <th class="all">Column 10</th>
      <th class="none">Column 11</th>
      <th class="all"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

**class "all":** Always display column irrespective of the screen size.

**class "none":** Don't display as a column, but show in the child row.

[**Source**](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/classes.html)

---

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/csnk79nx/)** is its working demo.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority):

> The column priority can also be defined by a data-priority attribute on the column's header cell (for example First name).