# Datatables Responsive always hidden column regardless of viewport

Tags: responsive-design, datatables

I have a generic DataTable with Responsive successfully configured. What I am after is to **force** DataTable to have a hidden column no matter what viewport it is displayed.

I tried searching for anything that might help me [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive) but no luck.

Comment: [DataTable responsive display certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273618/datatable-responsive-display-certain-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Found what I am trying to achieve. You gotta add **class="none"** to the header of column you intend to *always hide*.

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th class="none">Age</th>
            <th class="none">Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then simply initialize datatable with the Responsive plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```