# jQuery DataTables plugin not displaying all the columns specified

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin DataTables to display data in a .cfm (ColdFusion) page. Everything works *except* DataTables auto-truncates the columns (currently displays only 5 of my columns) and automatically creates a plus (+) button next to the value in the first column, that upon clicking, turns into a minus sign and the remaining columns are displayed below the current row!

I checked the DataTables documentation but it's really confusing and after trying (more like winging it) a few ways suggested on there, I'm stuck. How do I display *all* the columns in the table rather than letting DataTables control the number of columns visible and number of columns hidden?

My html table is as follows:

```
<table id="idsTbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" 
width="100%">
        <thead>
          
          <tr>
            <th>PRIMARY/FIRST ID</th>
            <th>SECOND ID</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING CO TYPE</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING COMPANY NAME</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING STATE</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING DATE</th>
            <th>PUB CREATED DATE</th>
            <th>OTHER DATE</th>
            <th>USER CREDENTIALS</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
             <th>PRIMARY/FIRST ID</th>
            <th>SECOND ID</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING CO TYPE</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING COMPANY NAME</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING STATE</th>
            <th>PUBLISHING DATE</th>
            <th>PUB CREATED DATE</th>
            <th>OTHER DATE</th>
            <th>USER CREDENTIALS</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

The javascript for the DataTables plugin is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xx.php?method=ids",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.length != 0) {
            //Footer section search capability
            $('#idsTbl tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" 
  />');
            });
            // /Footer section search capability
 var returnedIds = $("#idsTbl").DataTable({
                data: response,
                columns: [{
                        data: 'ID',
                       
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            var linkedId = '<a data-toggle="modal" data- target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#myModal" data-action="upd" data-id="' + oData.ID + '">' + oData.ID + '</a>';

                            $(nTd).html(linkedId );
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'ID2'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'TYPE'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'NAME'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'CO_NAME'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'STATE'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'PUB_DATE' 
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'MADE_DT',
                        "defaultContent": "N/A"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'USER_ID',
                        "defaultContent": "N/A"
                    },
                ],
                responsive: true,
                order: [0, 'asc'] 
            });

            // Apply the footer search
            idsTbl.columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
            // /Apply the footer search

        } else {
            console.log("There was no response from server!");
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("An Ajax server error was returned");
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
 });
 });
```

Note: Currently the table cuts off at 'PUBLISHING STATE', with 'PUBLISHING DATE' and the ones after it being displayed in an expandable section that is shown upon clicking a plus(+) sign next to the data in the first column. Also, if I change the responsive: true to responsive: false option, all the columns are displayed. BUT I don't want to lose the responsive nature of my webpage in order to display all the columns. Please suggest a viable solution.

Comment: Please look at this [DataTable responsive display certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43274199/3814721) which lets you decide which column(s) you want to display always and hide columns and show them when datatable is in responsive state. You just need to apply `class controls` at `th` of table.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't assign a class to a column, DataTables will automatically determine if a column should be shown or not. So if you want to force showing all columns on larger screen, you need to assign classes (**desktop, min-desktop** or **all**) to ALL columns.

To show all columns add **all** class like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th class="all">PRIMARY/FIRST ID</th>
            <th class="all">SECOND ID</th>
            <th class="all">PUBLISHING CO TYPE</th>
            <th class="all">PUBLISHING COMPANY NAME</th>
            <th class="all">PUBLISHING STATE</th>
            <th class="all">PUBLISHING DATE</th>
            <th class="all">PUB CREATED DATE</th>
            <th class="all">OTHER DATE</th>
            <th class="all">USER CREDENTIALS</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Check [official documentation here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove or set to false the property of responsive in your configurations. 
 
[Jquery Datatables Responsive Documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/)

`Responsive:false`

Following this concept for BS4:

`<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>`

[Responsive Tables BS4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

Comment: I stated that in my note - that I don't want to do that since that would mean losing responsiveness of my webpage; I'm looking for a way to do it without removing responsiveness.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes - using bootstrap 4.

Comment: Try following the [responsive-tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables) style for bootstrap 4.

`<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>`

Comment: Tried that but didn't make it responsive (upon resizing window to phone size, page was not responsive). This is what I added to my existing html: <div class="container table-responsive"> <table>........</table></div>

Comment: If you add the table-responsive class to the table tag? 
The only solutions I can think for now it's to put in the style property the overflow: scroll, to make it can scroll in smaller views

Answer (score 0):

just add this class to all header tags

```
<th class="all">...</th>
```